# QGuiApplication Exit Dialog box

Tags: qt, qml

We have a `QGuiApplication` and a pretty standard `main`function and then application starts in QML file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    // Some Processing...

   // Start the Application
    return a.exec();
}
```

I want to implement "Exit Dialog Box" i.e. When user clicks on "X", I want to show a Dialog box "Do you want to exit? Yes No ".

Is there any signal which I should wait for? `AboutToQuit()`is too late! and `CloseEvent()`is for QWidget.

I am using Qt5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [onClosing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#closing-signal) for QML windows. A root `ApplicationWindow` is a `Window` as well.

Note that the onClosing slot [is not properly recognized by Qt Creator](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13347) but it works.

Comment: I am getting error "Cannot assign to non-existent property "onClosing" ". I tried that too. My Main Window refuses to load... It remains blank and I get this error in Qt Creator's Application output window. I am using 3.1.1

Comment: @Swanand Add your QML code to the question please. I use it all the time and it works pretty solid.

Comment: Let's see... I will try what I am missing... and then I will post the code... Coz I have to remove all application logic :-) Thanks for quick reply... I will try... Or can you post any example code?

Comment: @Swanand See the minimal example in the bug report (second link of my answer). Hope that helps

Comment: @Swanand, if you were using a `Connections` element, ensure you have the property  `ignoreUnknownSignals` set to true